# Where's apachectl in Mac Yosimite

Tags: php, apache

Since the Apache is installed in Mac Yosimite in default. Why can't I find the `apachectl` under `/etc/apache2`? But I can still use `apachectl start` to start the server and visit 'http://localhost' successfully.

Anyone knows what's going on here?

Another question, I followed the tutorials [here](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2014/11/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-yosemite/)  , after I uncommented the line it says for PHP, the only difference is what I have is `LoadModule php4...`. But after I did that, the 'http://localhost' doesn't work.

It will be grateful if anyone can help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `apachectl` binary is not stored there. You can use `which` to locate the binary.

```
$ which apachectl
/usr/sbin/apachectl
```

PHP 4 is obsolete. I'm not sure what you are attempting to do, but I strongly recommend using PHP 5.4 or higher. Older versions of PHP are not receiving security patches.

Comment: Thanks. I found it. I just try to set up PHP developing environment. Can I just upgrade the current PHP4 to the latest?

Comment: You do not need to upgrade anything. PHP 5.5 is already installed.

Comment: @duskwuff Thanks. I found it. But why is there no LoadModule php5 in apache's configuration file?